# Layering UIViews so that bottom most layer can be seen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios4, background-image

I have a UIView to which i add a background image. Then to that view i add a scroll view. To the scroll view i add some UIButtons.

I would like to be able to set the scroll view to be transparent (still being able to see the UIButtons) so that i can see the background image underneath it, so that it shows between the buttons.

I have tried setting the scrollview background to `[UIColor clearColor]` but this doesnt work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to setting the `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`, you also have to set

```
scrollView.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: All i can see is still black underneath it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your image is loading?

Comment: I can change the color of the view containing the buttons to something like yellow and then I see those changes reflected. But if it clear then all I see is black. Is that the scroll view underneath?

Comment: Recreated XIB... must have been corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Change the UIScrollView.alpha level to 0.0f

Comment: If i did this, my subviews of the scroll view wouldnt be visible would they?

Comment: Override the subviews' setAlpha so they won't inherit the parent value.

Comment: You can also try changing the alpha level on just the background of that scrollview.  I don't think that will affect subviews.